# Hide specific nested tables in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, nested

```
<html>

<table id="tblMain">
  <tbody>
    <tr>No Sub Rows</tr>
    <tr>Parent Row 1</tr>
    <tr class="trSubTable">
      <td></td>
      <td colSpan="5"><table class="tblSub">Hide This</table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trSubTable">
      <td></td>
      <td colSpan="5"><table class="tblSub">Hide This Also</table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>No Sub Rows</tr>
    <tr>Parent Row 2</tr>
    <tr class="trSubTable">
      <td></td>
      <td colSpan="5"><table class="tblSub">Don't Hide This</table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>No Sub Rows</tr>
    <tr>Parent Row 3</tr>
    <tr class="trSubTable">
      <td></td>
      <td colSpan="5"><table class="tblSub">Hide This</table></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

I have tried a variety of JQuery methods to hide specific sub tables but none of these work.  I need to hide specific sub tables when I hide the row directly above.  Here is what I have tried.

```
$('#tblMain').each(function () {
//random logic code
if(show == 1)
{
  $(this).parent().children('.trSubTable').show();
}
else
{
    $(this).parent().children('.trSubTable').hide();
}
});
```

Comment: you need to specify # so $('#tblMain') and you want to trigger this on load so why use .each...

Comment: The focus is on the hiding aspect, not the loop.  The loop logic I have in my code works fine, it's the show() and hide() functionality for specific nested tables that I need to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tblMain .tblSub').each(function () {  //every sub table
//random logic code
if(show == 1)
{
  $(this).closest('.trSubTable').show(); //closest means 'go up until you find, which is the opposite of .find'
}
else
{
    $(this).closest('.trSubTable').hide();
}
});
```

Comment: This would work if I was hiding the sub rows directly but the "show" value is determined by the criteria in the row above .trSubTable.  I need to hide all rows under the parent.

Comment: whats rows above? please be more specific, there no 'show' anywhere, i just fixed your code...

Comment: "I need to hide specific sub tables when I hide the row directly above."  

Specifically written